# How can I do a query inside a query and set that as a condition for the main query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, inner-join

Org_table:

```
OrgName    Id    ParentID
 Org1      20    Null
 Org2      21    20
 Org3      22    21
 Org4      23    21
 Org5      24    22
 Org6      25    Null
```

In the table above Org1 is the super organisation and Org2 is the child of Org1. And Sub Org of Org2 is Org3 and Org4. and Org 5 is sub Org of Org3

I want to display all the details of these Org under the parent Org1 in my data grid. Here I know only the Org1 ID
so mysql query is like

```
Select OrgName from Org_table where ID= 20 and ParentID is 20;
```

But this query returns only Org1 and Org2, I have to return Org3, Org4 and Org5 also because it is under Org1. How can I do it. should I use some kind of loop if so how to do it. I am using c# do this is in my asp.net website.

During runtime I wont know which org is child of which ORg. SO I have to find the If the parent id is under the main Org

I want to do recursive query

Comment: Can you specify how do you want to show it??? because in a grid, you only need to replace parent ID with the name of the org.

Comment: I want to display all the org name, I dont want to display the ID. FOr the Parent Org1 I want to display all its child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have mysql on hand, but this should do what you need

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable (OrgName VARCHAR(10), Id INT, ParentID INT); 

INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT OrgName, Id, ParentID FROM org_table;

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TempTable WHERE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TempTable TempTableParent WHERE TempTableParent.ID = TempTable.ParentID AND TempTableParent.ParentID IS NOT NULL) ) DO

UPDATE TempTable SET ParentID = TempTableParent .parentID
FROM TempTable
INNER JOIN TempTable TempTableParent ON TempTableParent.id = TempTable.ParentID
WHERE TempTable.ParentID IS NOT NULL AND TempTableParent.ParentID IS NOT NULL

END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM TempTable
```

Not sure if the syntax on the update statement is entirely correct for mysql.. might need to be tweeked a little.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on the results and keep asking for the next related records.

First you run

```
Select OrgName, Id from Org_table where ID= 20 and ParentID = 20
```

And then for each result that has an Id != of 20 you should run the query again.
(Example for Org2)

```
Select OrgName, Id from Org_table where ParentID = 21
```

You can keep the results on a list an then obtain the distincts.

Comment: Yes, I just write the same but you overcome me.

Comment: Is it like a recursive query and How can I save the result to the DB, I was thinking like first get all the org id, and then do a query to display it in the grid

Comment: @Mark you can insert the partial results in a temporary table

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL does not support recursive queries/CTEs, you will have to emulate that (which is not, say, straightforward).

Here's an excellent tutorial on the subject:

http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

I will have the decency of not copying the code here :)